# Load a dict into memcache with python

Tags: python, dictionary, memcached

Have dict would like to load into memcache (complete newbie to memcache)

```
testd = { 'aaa': (1,23, 300),  'bbb': (37, 23, 300),  'ccc': (39, 62, 300), }
```

Would like to use `set_multi`...but havent been able to find an example of loading dicts.
Then how would I get the 'bbb' value? or 'bbb' and 'ccc' values together.

Below works but does not use `set_multi`

```
import memcache

mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)  
mc.set('keyed',testd)


xdata = mc.get('keyed')
print xdata['bbb']
```

Answer (score 2):

Saying something does not work is not helpful to you nor to future readers of this question.
Are you getting an error message?  If not, how is the result different from the result you expect?

How are you calling `set_multi`?  What argument(s) are you passing to `set_multi`?

Looking at [their source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-memcached-team/python-memcached/trunk/view/head:/memcache.py#L645), we see that `set_multi` takes a mapping as the first (non-self) argument.
Given that a Python dictionary is a mapping we can do:

```
mc.set_multi(testd)
```

What happens when you do that?  How does it differ from what you expect?
If you think you're encountering a bug, are you using the latest version of this library?
If not, please consider [a newer version](ftp://ftp.tummy.com/pub/python-memcached/python-memcached-latest.tar.gz).

Comment: @ bernie: I cant find examples that use "set_multi" or "get_multi" in python.

Answer (score 0):

memcached stores bytes, therefore if you store a mapping, make sure to decode the byte-typed result of a get  and reconstruct the mapping using json for instance

```
import json

raw_get = mc.get('keyed')
decoded_get = raw_get.decode("UTF-8")
xdata = json.loads(decoded_get.replace("'",'"'))
print xdata['bbb']
```

set_multi would be used to store multiple values with keys sharing a common prefix, it does not appear necessary in your use case.